# SQL Server 2008 - Create a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Efname VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
Elname VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
Efathername VARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
Ephone VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Eaddress VARCHAR(1000),
Erecruitment_date DATE NOT NULL,
Epension VARCHAR(25),
Ecomment VARCHAR(5000) DEFAULT'',
CONSTRAINT CXX_Epension CHECK(Epension NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%'), 
CONSTRAINT CXX_Ephone CHECK(Ephone NOT LIKE'%[^0-9]%'), 
CONSTRAINT CXX_Efname CHECK(Efname NOT LIKE'%[^ a-zA-zا-ی]%'), 
CONSTRAINT CXX_Elname CHECK(Elname NOT LIKE'%[^ a-zA-zا-ی]%'), 
CONSTRAINT CXx_Efathername CHECK(Efathername NOT LIKE'%[^ a-zA-zا-ی]%'), 

)
```

I want `EID` to be 10 characters long, and the first 6 characters are year and month of `Erecruitment_date` (example: `2001 02`). The next 4 should be the first four characters of `Ephone` (example: `0098`)

Comment: I don't get the question. Could you shed some more light?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your requirement is this:

1. First 6 digits of `EID` should be the year and month parts of `Erecruitment_date` e.g. '200501' for date '20050101'.
2. Next 4 digits of `EID` should be the first 4 digits of `Ephone` e.g. '1234' for phone number '12345678'

The constraint can then be written as:

```
CONSTRAINT CXX_Test CHECK
(substring(cast(eid as varchar),1,4)=cast(year(erecruitment_date) as varchar)
 AND substring(cast(eid as varchar),5,2) = right('00' + cast(month(erecruitment_date) as varchar),2)
 AND substring(cast(eid as varchar),7,4) = substring(ephone,1,4)
)
```

Note that you are storing `EID` as an `int`, so you need to ensure that the value coming in from your application is a 10-digit number to begin with. Otherwise, 1, 01, 001 and 000001 are all the same as far as `int` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Use substring() to select the particular year,date and phone number. 
Use concat() to concatenate them and assign to EID.

Reference :

[SUBSTRING](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)

[CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

But logically, this may not always produce a unique ID. Consider, x and y got recruited on the same day and same year. And say their phone numbers has the same first four digits. They will have same EID.